# Whatsapp in a virtual machine? (not Web Whatsapp)

Tags: android-emulator, virtual-machine, whatsapp

I need to share one Whatsapp account with my VA and need to run it in a phone emulator in my virtual machine (Windows Server).

I tried dozens of Andriod and iOS emulators but none worked in my virtual machine with Windows Server.

Web Whatsapp is not an option since it disconnects as soon as you open it in a different browser/tab/etc.

Any recommendations? Do you know of an emulator that works in a virtual machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can install  You wave player  in windows  it will work

IF you are using proxy mode : use proxifier  software install in  windows and setting use proxy  eg:  192.168.1.10  and select :  https mode

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out. 
Until now, I solved it by having an old phone plugged in all the time with the screen on so that whatsapp won't disconnect. Then I use web whatsapp wherever me or my VA are.

Comment: @ribhu, yes it still does! Just find a place where you can plug an old phone with a stable internet connection. I use the app Stay Alive to keep the screen on so that Whatsapp never goes offline.